# Grouping strings together in Vavr

Tags: java, functional-programming, vavr

I'm trying this code below:

```
final Map<Word, List<Word>> tuple2s = lowercase
            .groupBy(identity());
```

but this creates groups of single strings, basically like doing a `#split`:

```
LinkedHashMap((lorem, List(lorem)), (ipsum, List(ipsum)), (lorem, List(lorem)), (lorem, List(lorem)), (ipsum, List(ipsum)), (dolor, List(dolor)), (sit, List(sit)), (dolor, List(dolor)), (sit, List(sit)), (dolor, List(dolor)), (elit, List(elit)))
```

How do I fix this? The expected value is

```
LinkedHashMap((lorem, List(lorem, lorem, lorem)), (ipsum, List(ipsum, ipsum)), (dolor, List(dolor, dolor, dolor)), (sit, List(sit, sit)), (elit, List(elit)))
```

Comment: don't  you need word count? the word would be the key and the value would the number of occurrences

Comment: @AdamSiemion I do, in fact, try to implement such logic but because of this part, it does not work as expected. When I used that code with `.mapValues(group -> group.size())`, it just zipped all the single words with "1"s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a correct implementation of `equals` and `hashCode` in your `Word` class, that is based on the string content of the word that it represents. With that in place, `List.groupBy(...)` will result in what you would expect. Something similar to the following will suffice.

```
public class Word {
    private String word;

    public Word(String word) { this.word = word; }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return word; }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Word other = (Word) o;
        return Objects.equals(word, other.word);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() { return Objects.hash(word); }
}
```